# EF Query Sometimes Fast With Only CPU Uilization and Sometimes Slow with Database I/O Utilization SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, devexpress

We are using devexpress grid and LinqToEF in server mode although i'm not sure if that matters.  When our page first loads a grid sometimes it is slow and takes more than 60 seconds or times out when querying the SQL DB.  When this happens there is high Database I/O and Wait Tasks.  Other times the same query flies and you only see CPU utilization on the activity monitor.

The DB is quite large but we're only returning about 100 rows.  There are several indexes on the tables being pulled into the view that the devexpress grid uses and all those tables have indexes that have 0.01 fragmentation or less.

We'll rebuild indexes, reorganize and or restart the server and with no consistency as to which of those is done, the same query will go from have high DB I/O and slow, to CPU utilization spike and fast.  Slow is >60 seconds or timeout and fast is <2 seconds.

Same queries.

Does anyone know where I can start looking or some things to help troubleshoot this?

Comment: It would be **VERY** helpful to post the query's execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by checking to see if there are different execution plans.  Depending on the parameters you may or may not be passing, a poor execution plan could create the kind of results you are seeing.  Use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans a
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) b
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) c
WHERE   text LIKE '%SnippetOfQueryText%'
        AND b.dbid = DB_ID('DBName')
```

To check for multiple plans for the same query.  It'd be a good idea to call a stored procedure rather than using any dynamic sql statement.

You can use this SQL to find what table data is in the cache at any one point in time:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS cached_pages_count ,
        name AS BaseTableName ,
        IndexName ,
        IndexTypeDesc
FROM    sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors AS bd
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT s_obj.name ,
                            s_obj.index_id ,
                            s_obj.allocation_unit_id ,
                            s_obj.object_id ,
                            i.name IndexName ,
                            i.type_desc IndexTypeDesc
                     FROM   ( SELECT    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS name ,
                                        index_id ,
                                        allocation_unit_id ,
                                        object_id
                              FROM      sys.allocation_units AS au
                                        INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON au.container_id = p.hobt_id
                                                              AND ( au.type = 1
                                                              OR au.type = 3
                                                              )
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS name ,
                                        index_id ,
                                        allocation_unit_id ,
                                        object_id
                              FROM      sys.allocation_units AS au
                                        INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON au.container_id = p.partition_id
                                                              AND au.type = 2
                            ) AS s_obj
                            LEFT JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.index_id = s_obj.index_id
                                                       AND i.object_id = s_obj.object_id
                   ) AS obj ON bd.allocation_unit_id = obj.allocation_unit_id
WHERE   database_id = DB_ID()
GROUP BY name ,
        index_id ,
        IndexName ,
        IndexTypeDesc
ORDER BY obj.name;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for this query.  There is only one row that comes up.  Is there something from that row that I should be looking for?

Comment: No, you're looking for multiple rows.  I'd run that after you have a fast then slow execution.  The other thing you should do is post the execution plan.

Comment: Still waiting for the slow execution to happen again.  I should also mention we're using SQL 2014 but not inmemory stuff.  Is there a chance that it cache's all the data in the table after a while to make it speed up?  Is there something I can check on that?

Also, where would I get the execution plan if it doesn't show up in "recent expensive queries" ?  Try and catch it in a trace?

Comment: You can use Profiler to check the execution stats when it is run.  If you run it from SSMS, you can use Control + M to display the actual execution plan when running it.  When table data gets into the cache it's obviously much quicker to grab.  I have added a query to check for table data in the cache.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd vote this as the answer but looks like I have to get a little more rep.  Those two queries helped tracked down some good index overlap and missing ones in some executino plans.  I'm sure there's more I could do with the cache query up there but have to learn a little more on cache of SQL